# How to over write table bootstrap?

Tags: wordpress, bootstrap-table

I want to remove the "class = table-bordered" even though I didn't used this class in the first place.

I have tried: inline CSS, set the border to "0" and "none", but nothing happens. Also, as I inspect the element this class is appearing but on my code I never used it.

```
<table border ="0">

<table border ="none">

<table class = "table table-borderless">
```

I expect that it should work but it doesn't. On the inspect element option, It showing the class = "table-bordered".

Comment: Can you add class or id to any parent div? for example you added id to container div lets say "tableDiv" now apply css to table like #tableDiv table.table-bordered{ border: none !important;}

Comment: NEVER post images of code, errors or output! [mcve]

Comment: very sorry for late reply, just had something else to do. Anyways, have tried this code but apparently it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding class or id to parent div. Then Apply css to table. For example

HTML:

```
<section class="aboutbody">
      <div class="container" id="tableWrapper">
        <div class="row">
          <table class="table table-borderless table-bordered">
            <tr>
              <td align="center"></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
```

CSS:

```
 #tableWrapper table.table-bordered{ 
    border: none !important;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just find the answer to my question after searching for so long.
Here's my final code:

```
<div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="div-table">
                    <div class="div-table-row">
                          <div class="div-table-col">
                              <img class="wp-image-2511" style="width: 150px;" src="http://www.englishcollege.ac.ae/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/Thumbnail_July-2019-2.jpg" alt="">
                              <br>
                              &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                              <a rel="noreferrer noopener" href="http://www.englishcollege.ac.ae/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/July-2019.pdf" target="_blank"> July 2019 </a>
                          </div>
                        <div class="div-table-col">
                            <img class="wp-image-2511" style="width: 150px;" src="http://www.englishcollege.ac.ae/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/Thumbnail_June-2019-2.jpg" alt="">
                            <br>
                            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                            <a rel="noreferrer noopener" href="https://www.englishcollege.ac.ae/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/June-2019-06.pdf" target="_blank"> June 2019 </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="div-table-col">
                        <img class="wp-image-2511" style="width: 150px;" src="http://www.englishcollege.ac.ae/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/Thumbnail_May-2019.jpg" alt="">
                            <br>
                            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                            <a rel="noreferrer noopener" href="http://www.englishcollege.ac.ae/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/NL2019-05.pdf" target="_blank"> May 2019 </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="div-table-col">
                        <img class="wp-image-2511" style="width: 150px;" src="http://www.englishcollege.ac.ae/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/Thumbnail_April-2019.jpg" alt="">
                            <br>
                            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                            <a rel="noreferrer noopener" href="http://www.englishcollege.ac.ae/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/April-2019.pdf" target="_blank"> April 2019 </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <div class="div-table-row">
                        <div class="div-table-col">
                            <img class="wp-image-2511" style="width: 150px;" src="http://www.englishcollege.ac.ae/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/Thumbnail_March-2019.jpg" alt="">
                            <br>
                            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                            <a rel="noreferrer noopener" href="http://www.englishcollege.ac.ae/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/March-2019.pdf" target="_blank"> March 2019 </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="div-table-col">
                            <img class="wp-image-2511" style="width: 150px;" src="http://www.englishcollege.ac.ae/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/Thumbnail_February-2019.jpg" alt="">
                            <br>
                            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                            <a rel="noreferrer noopener" href="http://www.englishcollege.ac.ae/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/February-2019.pdf" target="_blank"> February 2019 </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="div-table-col">
                        <img class="wp-image-2511" style="width: 150px;" src="http://www.englishcollege.ac.ae/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/Thumbnail_January-2019.jpg" alt="">
                            <br>
                            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <a rel="noreferrer noopener" href="http://www.englishcollege.ac.ae/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/January-2019.pdf" target="_blank"> January 2019 </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="div-table-col">
                            <img class="wp-image-2511" style="width: 150px;" src="http://www.englishcollege.ac.ae/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/Thumbnail_December-2018.jpg" alt="">
                            <br>
                            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                            <a rel="noreferrer noopener" href="http://www.englishcollege.ac.ae/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/December-2018.pdf" target="_blank"> December 2018 </a>
                        </div>
                   </div>
              </div>

            </div>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
  .div-table {
  display: table;         
  width: auto;                
  border-spacing: 5px; /* cellspacing:poor IE support for  this */
  position:relative;
  left:70px;
}
.div-table-row {
  display: table-row;
  width: auto;
  clear: both;
}

.div-table-col {
  float: left; /* fix for  buggy browsers */
  display: table-column;         
  width: 289px;         
}
```